# How do you move a row from one table to another, and then delete the original row, within a loop?

Tags: postgresql

Trying to move a row from one table to another, and then delete it. I only want to move the information from two of the columns. It also contains a few constraints that I'm not sure I'm implementing correctly. I'm new to sql so i may have got it very wrong

```
DO $$DECLARE r record;
BEGIN
test date = 2020-01-01;
FOR r IN SELECT house_id, village_id FROM housecompletion INNER JOIN house, housecost WHERE house.house_id = housecompletion.house_id AND housecompletion.start_date + housecost.build_time < test AND housecompletion.house_id = housecost.house_id
LOOP
INSERT INTO villagehouse (house_id, village_id);
a integer = housecompletion_id;
DELETE FROM housecompletion WHERE housecompletion_id = a;
END LOOP;
END$$;
```

I got the error `ERROR:  syntax error at or near "test" LINE 3: test date = 2020-01-01;`

Comment: In pl/pgsql, you need to `DECLARE` all your variables up front.

Comment: This really shouldn't be a `LOOP` at all. Use a CTE: `WITH deleted_rows AS (DELETE FROM housecompletion USING house, hoe_cost WHERE … RETURNING *) INSERT INTO villagehouse (house_id, village_id) SELECT house_id, village_id FROM deleted_rows;`

Comment: As @Bergi, said, do this in SQL. It's important to learn to think in terms of declarative set operations instead of imperative sequential operations.